# Subtract a column in a dataframe from many columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe.   I'd like to subtract  the 2nd column from all other columns.  I can do it in a loop, but I'd like to do it in one call.   Here's my working loop code:

```
df <- data.frame(x = 100:101, y = 2:3,z=3:4,a = -1:0,b=4:5)

for( i in 3:length(df) ) {
    df[i] <- df[i] - df[2]
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you need to subtract the columns `3:ncol(df)` from the second column

```
df[3:ncol(df)] <- df[3:ncol(df)]-df[,2]
```

Comment: Perfect.   Thank you.   I tried that, but didn't have the comma before the 2 so got an error saying the dataframes didn't match.

Comment: @TPM The `df[2]` is still a dataframe and the dimensions won't be matching with the other dataset, while `df[,2]` is a vector and it will do the subtraction for each column of `df[3:ncol(df)]` by recycling

Comment: great solution. I want to mention that the same approach does not work in a datatable. For example if you use a for loop, and want to subtract one column from several other columns by doing so, the typical syntax `..` or `with=F` doesnt work

Comment: @ghx12 You may do `setDT(df)[, (3:ncol(df)) := lapply(.SD, \(x) x - colnmsecond), .SDcols = 3:ncol(df)]`

Answer (score 5):

Another solution using [`dplyr::mutate_at()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate_all.html) function

```r
# install.packages("dplyr", dependencies = TRUE)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(x = 100:101, y = 2:3, z = 3:4, a = -1:0, b = 4:5)
df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-matches("y"), -matches("x")), list(dif = ~ . - y))
#>     x y z  a b z_dif a_dif b_dif
#> 1 100 2 3 -1 4     1    -3     2
#> 2 101 3 4  0 5     1    -3     2
```

**Update**: starting from `dplyr 1.0+`, it's recommended to use [`across`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html)

```r
df %>%
  mutate(across(c(-matches("y"), -matches("x")), ~ . - y, .names = "{col}_dif"))
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48898121/mutate-multiple-variable-to-create-multiple-new-variables/

Answer (score 0):

This would also work - returns the 9 columns that you subtracted the second one from.

```
 df = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100,0,1),nrow = 10))
 df[,-2] - df[,2]
```

Comment: The OP wants to subtract only from `3:ncol(df)` , you may need `df[-c(1:2)]`  Having said that, this is basically the approach used by the solution I posted

Comment: @akrun, good catch, you're right. You would need that to get the same result as the code provided above