# Subtract two columns in a data frame

Tags: r, function, dataframe, subtraction

I have a data frame with several columns, I need to subtract the values of two columns from this data frame and add the resulted values as a new column in the same dataset.

Any idea on how to write function in R to do so?

Thanks in advance

Far

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. What did you try? Why did it fail?

Comment: data$newvalue <- data$var1 - data$var2? If this is indeed the answer, you will very likely benefit from reading some introductory materials on R.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28858393/subtract-a-column-in-a-dataframe-from-many-columns-in-r/

Answer (score 4):

Okay, let's say we have a data frame with two numeric columns, num1 and num2 (possibly with other columns too), which might look something like this:

```
    num1 num2
1    3   12
2    6   13
3    9   14
4   12   15
5   15   16
```

If we select the two columns and subtract one from the other, R automatically just subtracts their components element-wise, so this makes sense to try. Also, by setting the value of a new column, R automatically creates this column for us and adds it to the data frame (thanks Vongo for pointing this out in a comment).

Therefore, if we want to subtract column 'num1' from column 'num2' and add it as another column 'num3' to our data frame called 'df', we could try:

```
df$num3 <- df$num2 - df$num1
```

This gives the following data frame:

```
    num1 num2 num3
1    3   12    9
2    6   13    7
3    9   14    5
4   12   15    3
5   15   16    1
```

I hope that helps!

Note: if you want to reproduce the data frame I made for this example, the following two lines of code should do the trick:

```
df <- data.frame(3*1:5, 12:16)
names(df) <- c('num1', 'num2')
```

Comment: Why not simply `df$num3 <- df$num2 - df$num1` ?

Comment: It seems to me like R should get mad at you for referencing a column which doesn't exist, but that seems legit. I'll update the answer

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is to add another column to your existing data frame and populate it with the result. See an example below

```
DF = data.frame(num1 = runif(10, min = 1, max = 5), num2 = runif(10, min = 10, max = 15))
DF$num3 = DF$num2 - DF$num1
```