# dplyr summarise_at can't find extra variables inside function object

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to use `dplyr::summarise_at` on a collection of columns with a function object that uses an additional variable.

For example, consider the following data frame with two numeric variables and an indicator.

```
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

t1 <- data.frame(lg = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE),
                 x1 = 1:4,
                 x2 = 5:8)
```

Using `dplyr::funs()` inside `summarise_at` works:

```
t1 %>% summarise_at(c("x1", "x2"), funs(mean(. * lg)))
#>   x1 x2
#> 1  1  3
```

However, I prefer passing a `function` object to `summarise_at` - instead of a call to `dplyr::funs()` - so that `R CMD Check` doesn't complain about the unknown variable `.`.

Unfortunately, when I try to do this, `summarise_at` can't find the indicator variable `lg`.

```
t1 %>% summarise_at(c("x1", "x2"), function(x) mean(x * lg))
#> Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots): Evaluation error: object 'lg' not found.
```

Consequently, is there a way to pass a function object to `summarise_at` with extra variables inside the function object in this way?

Comment: In this specific case using `mean(x * t1$lg)` will work.

Comment: @AJP123: I don't think it's possible to do that without using either `funs` or `list`. Here is my reasoning https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52730562/mutate-impl-data-dots-evaluation-error-object-not-found/52730673#comment92417716_52730673

Comment: @Tung beautiful. Are you happy to post your comment as an answer and then I can accept it?

Comment: @AJP123: Sure. See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to do that without using either `funs` or `list` inside `summarize_at()`. My guess is that when we use the tilde `~` & `.` / `.x` or similarly `function(x)` & `x`, it creates an anonymous function with its own environment. Thus it only knows about the column variable that is passed through the `.` or `.x` but not the other variable in the data frame i.e. `lg`. Whereas, when we add `funs()` or `list()`, it probably inherits the whole environment which makes it aware of every column within the data frame not just the one passed via `.`

If you want a clearer code, maybe write a function then call it inside `summarise_at()`?

```r
multiplyx <- function(x, lg){
  result <- mean(x * lg)
  return(result)
}

t1 %>% summarise_at(c("x1", "x2"), funs(multiplyx(., lg)))
#>   x1 x2
#> 1  1  3

t1 %>% summarise_at(c("x1", "x2"), list(~ multiplyx(., lg)))
#>   x1 x2
#> 1  1  3
```

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52730562/mutate-impl-data-dots-evaluation-error-object-not-found/52730673#comment92417716_52730673)

Comment: I just asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59185751/dplyr-summarise-with-list-of-function-and-dependence-on-other-data-column). My problem is that I have a list of functions I want to use in `summarize_at`, not just one. I could manually write those functions in the `list(...)` within `summarize_at`, but that would be annoying. Is there a nice way to deal with my case?