# Dplyr summarise with list of function and dependence on other data column

Tags: group-by, dplyr, summarize

Sorry for the terrible title, but it's hard to explain. I have the following data and functions I want to summarize the data with:

```
library(tidyverse)

# generate data
df <- map(1:4, ~ runif(100)) %>% 
  set_names(c(paste0('V', 1:3), 'threshold')) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(group = sample(c('a', 'b'), 100, replace = T))

# generate function list
fun_factory_params <- 1:10
fun_factory <- function(param){
  function(v, threshold){
    sum((v * (threshold >= 1/2))^param)
  }
}
fun_list <- map(fun_factory_params, fun_factory)

df %>% head(n = 5)
      V1     V2     V3 threshold group
   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>
1 0.631  0.0209 0.0360     0.713 b    
2 0.629  0.674  0.174      0.693 b    
3 0.144  0.358  0.439      0.395 a    
4 0.0695 0.760  0.657      0.810 a    
5 0.545  0.770  0.719      0.388 b
```

I want to group `df` by the `group` variable and summarize `V1`, `V2` and `V3` in the following way: for each `V` of those variables and each value `n` in `fun_factory_params` (1 to 10), I want to compute `sum((V * (threshold >= 1/2))^n)`. To have results computed for each `n` in an elegant way, I created a function list `fun_list` through a function factory.

I tried the following and got the error:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(V1,V2,V3), fun_list, threshold = threshold)

Error in list2(...) : object 'threshold' not found
```

My issue comes from the `threshold` variable. I can't find a way to use the function list I build and tell R that the threshold argument has to be taken from each data group. I tried moving the threshold variable to a parameter of the function factory and to build the function list inside `summarise_at` through a `purrr::map` call, but I get the same issue. Essentially, the manipulations I make always somehow make R leave the right environment to evaluate threshold by group. Using `.$threshold` returns the threshold variable for the *entire* data, so that does not work.

However, the fact that the following code works (but only for a given value of n at a time) makes me think that there is a way to evaluate threshold correctly.

```
n <- 1
df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(V1,V2,V3), ~ sum((. * (threshold >= 1/2))^n))
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to have `threshold` being evaluated in the right environment (grouped data) when written as an additional argument to `summarise_at` functions: you need to quote `threshold` with `quo`.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(V1,V2,V3), fun_list, threshold = quo(threshold))
```

I'm not 100% of my understanding. I think that quoting makes sure that threshold will be evaluated using the environment it was found in at the time `quo` was called, which is the grouped data (what we want). Essentially, quoting a variable makes it carry not only its name, but also sets a reference to the environment we want that variable to be evaluated with. Without quoting, `threshold`'s evaluation was attempted in a different environment (not sure which one...) where the variable does not exist. General information about programming in `dplyr` can be found [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html).

Please let me know if this solution still has something wrong / not robust.