# Apply a summarise condition to a range of columns when using dplyr group_by?

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

Suppose we want to `group_by()` and `summarise` a massive data.frame with very many columns, but that there are some large groups of consecutive columns that will have the same `summarise` condition (e.g. `max`, `mean` etc)

Is there a way to avoid having to specify the `summarise` condition for each and every column, and instead do it for **ranges of columns**?

#### Example

Suppose we want to do this:

```
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(max(Sepal.Length), mean(Sepal.Width), mean(Petal.Length), mean(Petal.Width))
```

but note that 3 consecutive columns have the same `summarise` condition, `mean(Sepal.Width), mean(Petal.Length), mean(Petal.Width)`

Is there a way to use some method like `mean(Sepal.Width:Petal.Width)` to specify the condition for the range of columns, and hence a avoiding having to type out the summarise condition multiple times for all the columns in between)

#### Note

The iris example above is a small and manageable example that has a range of 3 consecutive columns, but actual use case has ~hundreds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The upcoming version [1.0.0](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/master/NEWS.md) of `dplyr` will have [`across()`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tidyverse/dplyr/master/vignettes/colwise.Rmd) function that does what you wish for

> **Basic usage**

> `across()` has two primary arguments:

> - The first argument, `.cols`, selects the columns you want to operate on.
>   It uses tidy selection (like `select()`) so you can pick variables by
>   position, name, and type.

> - The second argument, `.fns`, is a function or list of functions to apply to
>   each column. This can also be a purrr style formula (or list of formulas)
>   like `~ .x / 2`. (This argument is optional, and you can omit it if you just want
>   to get the underlying data; you'll see that technique used in
>   `vignette("rowwise")`.)

```r
### Install development version on GitHub first
# install.packages("devtools")
# devtools::install_github("tidyverse/dplyr")
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
```

Control how the names are created with the `.names` argument which takes a [glue](http://glue.tidyverse.org/) spec:

```r
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(
    across(c(Sepal.Width:Petal.Width), ~ mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE), .names = "mean_{col}"),
    across(c(Sepal.Length), ~ max(.x, na.rm = TRUE), .names = "max_{col}")
    )
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>   Species    mean_Sepal.Width mean_Petal.Leng~ mean_Petal.Width max_Sepal.Length
#> * <fct>                 <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>
#> 1 setosa                 3.43             1.46            0.246              5.8
#> 2 versicolor             2.77             4.26            1.33               7  
#> 3 virginica              2.97             5.55            2.03               7.9
```

Using multiple functions

```r
my_func <- list(
  mean = ~ mean(., na.rm = TRUE),
  max  = ~ max(., na.rm = TRUE)
)

iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(across(where(is.numeric), my_func, .names = "{fn}.{col}"))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 9
#>   Species    mean.Sepal.Length max.Sepal.Length mean.Sepal.Width max.Sepal.Width
#> * <fct>                  <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>           <dbl>
#> 1 setosa                  5.01              5.8             3.43             4.4
#> 2 versicolor              5.94              7               2.77             3.4
#> 3 virginica               6.59              7.9             2.97             3.8
#>   mean.Petal.Length max.Petal.Length mean.Petal.Width max.Petal.Width
#> *             <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>           <dbl>
#> 1              1.46              1.9            0.246             0.6
#> 2              4.26              5.1            1.33              1.8
#> 3              5.55              6.9            2.03              2.5
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Yup. Very awesome. Check out [rowwise](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/master/vignettes/rowwise.Rmd) too

Comment: Also good to know. I think they were working to phase out or move away from `rowwise()` at some point, but reading through quickly on GH seems they have decided against that. Happy this is the case, prefer `rowwise` relative to using `pmap` inside `mutate` or other "hacky" solutions.

Answer (score 3):

Since `summarise` collapses the rows and hence we cannot further apply any functions to it, we can use `mutate_at` instead, select range of columns to apply function and then select 1st row from every group.

```
library(dplyr)

iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(Sepal.Width:Petal.Width), mean) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(Sepal.Length), max) %>%
  slice(1L)

#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species   
#         <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>     
#1          5.8        3.43         1.46       0.246 setosa    
#2          7          2.77         4.26       1.33  versicolor
#3          7.9        2.97         5.55       2.03  virginica
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `pmap` from `purrr` to apply various functions to various columns and then join back together at the end. Note the use of `lst` from `purrr` so we can refer to previously named objects in the list construction. This allows us to analyze the same column with multiple functions, such as Sepal.Length below.

```r
library(tidyverse)

lst(a = list("Sepal.Length", names(select(iris, Sepal.Length:Petal.Width))),
    b = list("max" = max, "mean" = mean),
    c = names(b)) %>%
  pmap(function(a, b, c) {
    iris %>%
      group_by(Species) %>%
      summarize_at(a, b) %>%
      rename_at(a, paste0, "_", c)
  })  %>%
  reduce(inner_join, by = "Species")
#> # A tibble: 3 x 6
#>   Species Sepal.Length_max Sepal.Length_me~ Sepal.Width_mean Petal.Length_me~
#>   <fct>              <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>
#> 1 setosa               5.8             5.01             3.43             1.46
#> 2 versic~              7               5.94             2.77             4.26
#> 3 virgin~              7.9             6.59             2.97             5.55
#> # ... with 1 more variable: Petal.Width_mean <dbl>
```