# Make rowwise operations on a vector of columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to understand how I can get the row-wise minimum for a set of columns that are defined in a vector of strings, i.e. how to get the following output with the following input:

Input:

```
t <- data.frame(x= c(1,2,3,4), y= c(2,3,4,5), z = c(4,5,6,7))
vars. <- c('x', 'y')
```

My (not working) suggestion:

```
t %>% rowwise %>% mutate(min_x_y = min(vars(vars.)))
```

Output should be:

```
  x y z min_x_y
1 1 2 4       1
2 2 3 5       2
3 3 4 6       3
4 4 5 7       4
```

Comment: Aside from the part of having the column names in a vector, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31598935/5325862) has several ideas for row-wise summary stats

Comment: Check out the new functionality of [`dplyr` 1.0](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/03/dplyr-1-0-0-is-coming-soon/) that includes an `across` function. Also discussed in this recent [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60574290/apply-a-summarise-condition-to-a-range-of-columns-when-using-dplyr-group-by/60574568?noredirect=1#comment107166138_60574568).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `pmap_dbl` from `purrr`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

t %>% mutate(min_x_y = pmap_dbl(select(., vars.), min))

#  x y z min_x_y
#1 1 2 4       1
#2 2 3 5       2
#3 3 4 6       3
#4 4 5 7       4
```

---

A base R version would be

```
t$min_x_y <- do.call(pmin, t[vars.])
```

Answer (score 2):

Yet another alternative to the approaches already suggested would be to use a combination of tidy evaluation and `pmin`:

```
# convert character vector of variable names into symbols
vars. <- c('x', 'y') %>% dplyr::syms()

# use tidy evaluation to pass symbols to pmin inside a mutate call
t %>% 
  mutate(min_x_y = pmin(!!!vars.))
#>   x y z min_x_y
#> 1 1 2 4       1
#> 2 2 3 5       2
#> 3 3 4 6       3
#> 4 4 5 7       4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in different ways, one is;

```
t <- data.frame(x= c(1,2,3,4), y= c(2,3,4,5), z = c(4,5,6,7))
vars. <- c('x', 'y')

t$min_x_Y=t(as.data.frame(t(t)) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(min)))
```