# Slow dplyr query in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I've got a bit of code in R:

```
library(dplyr)

df_temp <- df %>%
   group_by(policy_number, policy_year) %>% 
   summarise(term_start_date  = last(term_start_date),
             term_end_date    = last(term_end_date),
             on_cover_after   = last(on_cover_after),
             termination_code = last(termination_code),
             termination_date = last(termination_date))
```

The main table `df` is about 700,000 rows by 130 columns. Grouped by `policy_number` and `policy_year` there are about 300,000 (`policy_number`/`policy_year`) groupings.

4 of the 5 columns that I've referred to in `last()` are dates.

This query takes about 3 minutes to run, which is a nuisance because the rest of my code runs quite briskly. I'm hoping to speed it up. Is there anything I could try that might help please?

(ideally would supply a reprex but how could I do that here? not sure)

Thank you.

Edit: since I'm always using the last record for a given (`policy_number`/`policy_year`) pair, is there some code I could write along the lines of:

```
df_temp <- df %>%
   group_by(policy_number, policy_year) %>% 
   mutate(counter = 1:n()) %>%
   filter(counter == max(counter)) %>%
   select(term_start_date,
          term_end_date,
          on_cover_after,
          termination_code,
          termination_date)
```

?

Comment: You can supply a reprex by sharing code to simulate data. Use `set.seed` first so it's fully reproducible. Something like `n = 7e5; df = tibble(policy_number = sample(1:1e5, size = n, replace = TRUE), policy_year = sample(2017:2019, size = n, replace = TRUE), ...)`

Comment: As to your edit, `df %>%  group_by(policy_number, policy_year) %>% select(term_start_date,
          term_end_date,
          on_cover_after,
          termination_code,
          termination_date) %>% slice(n())` would work. Not sure if it's faster. Putting the `select` *before* the `summarize` (or the `slice`, in this case) might help too. Add some data and we'll do some benchmarks.

Comment: Is there a column that the row order based on? For providing a `data.table` solution that would be helpful to know.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `summarise`, use `summarise_at`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(policy_number, policy_year) %>%
   summarise_at(vars(term_start_date, term_end_date,
       term_end_date,termination_code, termination_date), last)
```

Comment: ohhhh that's interesting. Thank you. I wasn't aware of summarise_at(). I will try it tomorrow.

Answer (score 4):

There is a great source [here](http://datascience.la/dplyr-and-a-very-basic-benchmark/) about this. The author makes several great suggestions (see his comments section). I would consider aggregating your data with data.table, or if you stick with dplyr then consider defining a key. Some metrics of relative benchmarks:

[image]

[From source](http://datascience.la/dplyr-and-a-very-basic-benchmark/)

Comment: Another great source [here](https://atrebas.github.io/post/2019-03-03-datatable-dplyr/) on comparable solutions in dplyr vs data.table

Answer (score 3):

You can try either [`dtplyr`](https://github.com/tidyverse/dtplyr) package (`data.table` backend for `dplyr`) or [`data.table`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table) package directly to speed up the calculation. See the benchmark below for `iris` dataset

```r
library(microbenchmark)
library(data.table)
library(dtplyr)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

# create a “lazy” data table for dtplyr
iris2 <- lazy_dt(iris)

# create a data table for data.table
dt <- setDT(copy(iris))

# dplyr calculation
dplyr_func <- function() {
  iris %>% 
    group_by(Species) %>% 
    summarise_at(vars(Sepal.Length:Petal.Width), last)      
}

# dtplyr calculation
dtplyr_func <- function() {
  iris2 %>% 
    group_by(Species) %>% 
    summarise_at(vars(Sepal.Length:Petal.Width), last)  %>% 
    as_tibble()      
}

# data.table calculation
dt_func <- function() {
  dt[ 
    , lapply(.SD, last)
    , Species]
}
```

Benchmark

```r
microbenchmark(
  dplyr_func(),
  dtplyr_func(),
  dt_func(),
  times = 1000L
)

#> Unit: microseconds
#>           expr    min     lq   mean median     uq   max neval cld
#>   dplyr_func() 4605.0 4892.9 5180.3 4999.9 5155.1 23253  1000   c
#>  dtplyr_func() 2503.9 2633.6 2885.0 2714.3 2812.2 39490  1000  b 
#>      dt_func()  949.2 1155.3 1848.1 2036.0 2302.1  7251  1000 a
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: In addition to `summarise_at`, you can also use `across` in the future release v1.0.0 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60574290/apply-a-summarise-condition-to-a-range-of-columns-when-using-dplyr-group-by