# How to subtract two columns using tidyverse mutate with columns named by external variables

Tags: r, tidyverse, dplyr, across

I’d like to dynamically assign which columns to subtract from each other. I’ve read around and looks like I need to use `all_of`, and maybe `across` ([How to subtract one column from multiple columns in a dataframe in R using dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64081674/how-to-subtract-one-column-from-multiple-columns-in-a-dataframe-in-r-using-dplyr), [How to you use objects in dplyr filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69058141/how-to-you-use-objects-in-dplyr-filter)). I can get it working for one variable in a mutate phrase (e.g. `mutate(y = all_of(x))`), but I can’t seem to do even simple calculations using two. Here’s a simplified example of what I want to do:

```
var1 <- c("Sepal.Length")
var2 <- c("Sepal.Width")

result <- iris %>%
  mutate(calculation = all_of(var1) - all_of(var2))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We may use `.data` to subset the column as a vector.  The `all_of/any_of` are used along with `across` to loop across the columns

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>%
  mutate(calculation = .data[[var1]] - .data[[var2]])%>%
  head
```

-output

```
Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species calculation
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa         1.6
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa         1.9
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa         1.5
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa         1.5
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa         1.4
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa         1.5
```

---

Or may also use `cur_data()`

```
iris %>%
    head %>%
    mutate(calculation = cur_data()[[var1]] - cur_data()[[var2]])
```

-output

```
 Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species calculation
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa         1.6
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa         1.9
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa         1.5
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa         1.5
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa         1.4
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa         1.5
```

---

Or another option is to pass both the variables in `across`, and then `reduce` with `-`

```
library(purrr)
iris %>%
   head %>%
   mutate(calculation = reduce(across(all_of(c(var1, var2))), `-`))
```

-output

```
Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species calculation
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa         1.6
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa         1.9
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa         1.5
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa         1.5
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa         1.4
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa         1.5
```

---

Or could convert to `sym`bol and evaluate (`!!`)

```
iris %>% 
   head %>% 
   mutate(calculation = !! rlang::sym(var1) - !! rlang::sym(var2))
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species calculation
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa         1.6
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa         1.9
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa         1.5
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa         1.5
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa         1.4
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa         1.5
```

---

Or if we want to use `all_of` in `across`, just subset the column with `[[`

```
iris %>% 
   head %>% 
   mutate(calculation = across(all_of(var1))[[1]] - 
                         across(all_of(var2))[[1]])
Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species calculation
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa         1.6
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa         1.9
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa         1.5
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa         1.5
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa         1.4
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa         1.5
```

The reason we need to subset is because, `across` by default will update the original column when the `.names` is not present.  The `calculation` will be a data.frame with a single column

```
out <- iris %>%
    head %>% 
    mutate(calculation = across(all_of(var1)) -
           across(all_of(var2)))
out
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species Sepal.Length
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa          1.6
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa          1.9
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa          1.5
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa          1.5
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa          1.4
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa          1.5

str(out)
data.frame':    6 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4
 $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9
 $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7
 $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4
 $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1
 $ calculation :'data.frame':   6 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ Sepal.Length: num  1.6 1.9 1.5 1.5 1.4 1.5
```

Comment: I don´t understand. I tried `library(rlang)  iris %>% 
    mutate(calculation = !!enquo(var1) - !!enquo(var2))` but it does not work

Comment: @TarJae 'var1', 'var2' are string objects and `en` prefix is used wihtin a function.  `enquo` is used mostly when you are trying to convert to quosure by passing a unquoted variable in a function.

Comment: The .data option works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

We could use `get` to access the variable values where the name of variable is stored in a string (thanks to akrun for assist):

```
iris %>% 
    mutate(calculation = get(var1) - get(var2))
```

```
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species calculation
          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>         <dbl>
 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa          1.6
 2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa          1.9
 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa          1.5
 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa          1.5
 5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa          1.4
 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa          1.5
 7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa          1.2
 8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa          1.6
 9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa          1.5
10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa          1.8
# ... with 140 more rows
```