# How subtract two columns correlativelly in a data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, across

#### Context

We would like to know how subtract columns, two by two. Specifically, we want to subtract the columns of the dataframe as follow:

- the `u_2018` - `u_2019`.
- the `u_2019` - `u_2020`.
- the `u_2020` - `u_2021`.
- the `u_2021` - `u_2022`.

We looked for a optimal solution in the several stackoverflow question posts, like this ([How to subtract two columns using tidyverse mutate with columns named by external variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69154900/how-to-subtract-two-columns-using-tidyverse-mutate-with-columns-named-by-externa)), but the only **undesired** approach achieved is datiled in the R code used section. The R session version is `4.2.0` and the `dplyr` package version is `1.0.9`.

#### Input data in R session

```
> dat
# A tibble: 6 × 5
          u_2018        u_2019        u_2020        u_2021        u_2022
           <int>         <int>         <int>         <int>         <int>
 1         90035         88015         76135         50725         16517
 2            20            NA            NA         13792         12793
 3           555           620         15032         19309          6479
 4         11171         11782         10281          8974          3901
 5            NA        116896         40169         13191          3610
```

#### R code used

```
dat %>%
  mutate(
    diff_2018_2019 = u_2018 - u_2019,
    diff_2019_2020 = u_2019 - u_2020,
    diff_2020_2021 = u_2020 - u_2021,
    diff_2021_2022 = u_2021 - u_2022)
```

#### Question

We would like to know the optimal solution to subtract two by two columns. Maybe one approach includes `mutate_at()` or `across` to obtain the differences between and save the subtraction in new columns.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `pmap_dfr` + `diff`:

```r
library(purrr)

pmap_dfr(df, ~ -diff(c(...))) %>%
  set_names(~ as.integer(sub('u_', '', .x)) %>% paste('dif', . - 1, ., sep = '_'))

# # A tibble: 5 × 4
#   dif_2018_2019 dif_2019_2020 dif_2020_2021 dif_2021_2022
#           <int>         <int>         <int>         <int>
# 1          2020         11880         25410         34208
# 2            NA            NA            NA           999
# 3           -65        -14412         -4277         12830
# 4          -611          1501          1307          5073
# 5            NA         76727         26978          9581
```

Note that `diff()` defaults to subtract the former from the latter, so you need to invert the sign with `-diff()`.

---

###### Data

```r
df <- structure(list(u_2018 = c(90035L, 20L, 555L, 11171L, NA), u_2019 = c(88015L, 
NA, 620L, 11782L, 116896L), u_2020 = c(76135L, NA, 15032L, 10281L, 40169L),
u_2021 = c(50725L, 13792L, 19309L, 8974L, 13191L), u_2022 = c(16517L, 
12793L, 6479L, 3901L, 3610L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"))
```

Comment: Thanks to improve the estructure of the post. Also your solution works fine. Thanks so much @Darren Tsai

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(map2_dfc(names(.)[-ncol(.)], names(.)[-1], ~ df[.x] - df[.y]) %>%
    set_names(str_c("new", 1:(ncol(df)-1))))

#>   u_2018 u_2019 u_2020 u_2021 u_2022 new1   new2  new3  new4
#> 1  90035  88015  76135  50725  16517 2020  11880 25410 34208
#> 2     20     NA     NA  13792  12793   NA     NA    NA   999
#> 3    555    620  15032  19309   6479  -65 -14412 -4277 12830
#> 4  11171  11782  10281   8974   3901 -611   1501  1307  5073
#> 5     NA 116896  40169  13191   3610   NA  76727 26978  9581
```

Or in `base R`:

```r
cbind(df, setNames(df[-ncol(df)] - df[-1], paste0("new", 1:(ncol(df)-1))))

#>   u_2018 u_2019 u_2020 u_2021 u_2022 new1   new2  new3  new4
#> 1  90035  88015  76135  50725  16517 2020  11880 25410 34208
#> 2     20     NA     NA  13792  12793   NA     NA    NA   999
#> 3    555    620  15032  19309   6479  -65 -14412 -4277 12830
#> 4  11171  11782  10281   8974   3901 -611   1501  1307  5073
#> 5     NA 116896  40169  13191   3610   NA  76727 26978  9581
```

Comment: how does the columns reference work with `-ncol(.)` and `-1`?  do you know if there's a `purrr` tutorial/example of that?

Comment: @Eric: I am not sure I understand your question: With `map2_dfc`, I am iterating the columns indexes of the columns of df, pair of indexes by pair of indexes: `(1,2)`, `(2,3)`,... Therefore, it is needed to remove the index of last column of `df` with `-ncol(df)`, and the index of the first column of `df` (`-1`).

Comment: Great work! Maybe you could give more effort to create custom column names to make this answer more complete.

Comment: Thanks, @DarrenTsai! I am a bit lazy today: If the OP needs more meaningful column names, he can accept your answer, which is also a great solution!

Comment: I have just upvoted your solution, as it is a clever one, @DarrenTsai!

Comment: Thanks everybody for your contributions.

Answer (score 1):

```r
df <- structure(list(u_2018 = c(90035L, 20L, 555L, 11171L, NA), u_2019 = c(88015L, 
NA, 620L, 11782L, 116896L), u_2020 = c(76135L, NA, 15032L, 10281L, 40169L),
u_2021 = c(50725L, 13792L, 19309L, 8974L, 13191L), u_2022 = c(16517L, 
12793L, 6479L, 3901L, 3610L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"))

library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  mutate(rename_with(df[-ncol(df)] - df[-1], ~ str_replace(., 'u', 'diff')))
#>   u_2018 u_2019 u_2020 u_2021 u_2022 diff_2018 diff_2019 diff_2020 diff_2021
#> 1  90035  88015  76135  50725  16517      2020     11880     25410     34208
#> 2     20     NA     NA  13792  12793        NA        NA        NA       999
#> 3    555    620  15032  19309   6479       -65    -14412     -4277     12830
#> 4  11171  11782  10281   8974   3901      -611      1501      1307      5073
#> 5     NA 116896  40169  13191   3610        NA     76727     26978      9581
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

We could use `across2` from `dplyover`

```
library(dplyover)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(across2(-last_col(), -1, `-`,
    .names_fn = ~str_replace(.x, "u", "dif")))
```

-output

```
 u_2018 u_2019 u_2020 u_2021 u_2022 dif_2018_u_2019 dif_2019_u_2020 dif_2020_u_2021 dif_2021_u_2022
1  90035  88015  76135  50725  16517            2020           11880           25410           34208
2     20     NA     NA  13792  12793              NA              NA              NA             999
3    555    620  15032  19309   6479             -65          -14412           -4277           12830
4  11171  11782  10281   8974   3901            -611            1501            1307            5073
5     NA 116896  40169  13191   3610              NA           76727           26978            9581
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(u_2018 = c(90035L, 20L, 555L, 11171L, NA), u_2019 = c(88015L, 
NA, 620L, 11782L, 116896L), u_2020 = c(76135L, NA, 15032L, 10281L, 
40169L), u_2021 = c(50725L, 13792L, 19309L, 8974L, 13191L), u_2022 = c(16517L, 
12793L, 6479L, 3901L, 3610L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5"))
```